# How to process a JSON file to include only 4 fields from each item?

Tags: python, json, filtering

This is what my JSON file looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 13445,
        "uuid": "bf1923c5-a198-409b-851e-c67f7b8a661e",
        "created_at": "2021-07-27 12:41:31.715922",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-10 21:41:41.857982",
        "meta": {
            "osm_id": null,
            "google_maps_place_id": "ChIJO4sAE5d-1EARsPwZh_s6eX4"
        },
        "type": "VILLAGE",
        "name": {
            "en": "Dіbrіvka",
            "ru": "Дибривка",
            "uk": "Дібрівка"
        },
        "public_name": {
            "en": "village Dіbrіvka",
            "ru": "п. Дибривка",
            "uk": "с. Дібрівка"
        },
        "post_code": [
            "09226"
        ],
        "katottg": "UA32120130090047792",
        "koatuu": "3222281602",
        "lng": 30.9903521,
        "lat": 49.88724620000001,
        "parent_id": 1051
    }
]
```

With the following code I can read JSON and convert it to a Python `dict`

```
with open('ua_locations.json', 'r',  encoding="utf-8") as user_file:
    file_contents = user_file.read()
    json_object = json.loads(file_contents)[0]

print(type(json_object))
print(json_object['id']['public_name']['lng']['lat'])
```

How can I include only 4 fields: id, public name, lng, lat for each element in the `list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list (or tuple) of the keys you're interested in. You can then combine a dictionary comprehension within a list comprehension as follows:

```
import json

INPUT_FILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/ua_locations.json'
KEYS = ('id', 'public_name', 'lng', 'lat')

with open(INPUT_FILE) as j:
    for d in [{k: item.get(k) for k in KEYS} for item in json.load(j)]:
        print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'id': 13445, 'public_name': {'en': 'village Dіbrіvka', 'ru': 'п. Дибривка', 'uk': 'с. Дібрівка'}, 'lng': 30.9903521, 'lat': 49.88724620000001}
```

Comment: @O.MartynenkoakaSkywalker You don't need to call read() on the file object. Notice that the code uses json.load() rather than json.loads()